# Find a product using a given patent / Contact a patent owner

Tags: product, patent-use, commercial-use, unused-patent

In a search for a specific tool, I found a patent describing exactly what I need. However, I couldn't find any tool on the market using the technology it describes. What can I do?

1. Is there a way to contact the patent holder and ask him if he used it for commercial purposes, and if so, where/how?
2. I though if the product doesn't exist on the market, I could produce it on my own, giving royalites to the beneficial owner. But does a patent holder have the right to not use it at all and forbid anyone else to do so?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to contact the patent holder and ask him if he used it
>   for commercial purposes, and if so, where/how?

Search through the file history using USPTO PAIR to find out inventor information.  Search patent assignments using USPTO assignment search to find out owner information.

> But does a patent holder have the right to not use it at all and
>   forbid anyone else to do so?

Yes, of course.  Many patents describe technology that is never used.  A patent owner does not "forbid" others from using patented technology.  The patent owner may sue others for alleged infringement.